# How to add Open Sources Code Files in Eclipse, so that `Ctrl+Shift+R` shows the Source Code Files?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, m2eclipse, jbpm

I am using `Eclipse Luna, JDK1.7, JBPM7 and Maven in MyProject`.

I want to debug my `JBPM source files(TaskEventsServiceImpl.java,TaskContentServiceImpl.java)`, so i downloaded the [Source files of JBPM](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/jbpm)

**My Question :**

How to add these files into my Project so that i can view the `file(TaskContentServiceImpl.java)` when i search in `Ctrl+Shift+R`?

**WorkDone:**

I added the following source folder in my `Build Path of **MyProject** and Restarted my Eclipse`.
But i am not able to view the file in my `Ctrl+Shift+R`.

Please, let me know the process of configuration so that i can view my source files when i search in `Ctrl+Shift+R`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Ctrl+Shift+R will only show you resources in t he current work space. To open a file on the project class-path I believe **Ctrl+Shift+T** should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you :) Is there a way to view the source file(.java) , bcz CTRL+SHIFT+T opens .class files

Comment: If you have the source file attached to the Jar, CTRL+SHIFT+T will open the source file. To attach the source file to the Jar, there are different mechanism depending on how your doing dependency management. The manual way would be Right Click on Project --> Properties --> Libraries --> Drill to Jar in Question --> Source Attachment and add the source files folder/jar